# malformed node or string when passing dict of lists to multiprocessor

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to use python's multiprocessor to apply a function to a very large dataframe.  However, when I attempt to do so, I'm met with the following error:

> Error in Getting Maps: malformed node or string: 3923    {'rings': [[[-166.126674000358, 53.99072599987...
> 3924    {'rings': [[[-162.374114000099, 54.62116300012...
> 3925    {'rings': [[[-159.575114000372, 54.82437400003...
> 3926    {'rings': [[[-179.109334999804, 51.30097499985...

The error is referring to the dict of lists, in the `SHAPE` column of the dataframe.  This error occurs on the line where I attempt to apply `pool.map`.  Is there a particular way in which I need to pass this data in?

My code is below:

```
group_counter =0
def parallelize_processing(df_grouped):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        results = pool.map(process_group, [group for _, group in df_grouped])
            
    return pd.concat(results)




def process_group(group):
    # Apply process_item to each item in the group
    # print("Group length is ",len(group))
    global group_counter
    group_counter += 1
    if group_counter % 10 == 0:
        print("Processing Group",group_counter)
    # area_id = group.iloc[0]['census_block_group_geoid']
    # print("\n Aread Id is " , area_id)
    # area_id_type =  "census_block_group_geoid"
    return get_osmnx_stats(group)

counter = [0]
processedResults = parallelize_processing(df.groupby("STATE_ABBR"))
print(processedResults)
```

A sample of the dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 1, 10010201001, 1, 346.4, 572, 575, 344.6,
    "{'rings': [[[-86.4996507402442, 32.4754860835371], [-86.4947807386288, 32.4737880832872], [-86.4939147384403, 32.4734700834128], [-86.4923967383237, 32.4729330833056], [-86.485726735661, 32.4706590831919], [-86.4820737347616, 32.4729810838308], [-86.4818587346765, 32.47306708335], [-86.4808617349668, 32.4734900839575], [-86.4796867349819, 32.4739680836048], [-86.47945473428, 32.4736320838323], [-86.4792497342405, 32.4733040834944], [-86.4780417337453, 32.4711200835862], [-86.4774887335514, 32.4701380834169], [-86.4769777331903, 32.4691670831793], [-86.4768937335247, 32.4690310825582], [-86.4761127328268, 32.4676530822682], [-86.4758207327487, 32.467145082172], [-86.4757107331439, 32.4669930828214], [-86.4753097332859, 32.4663530821834], [-86.4752447329885, 32.4662350823603], [-86.4752077331786, 32.4661470822372], [-86.4750907330028, 32.4659420822719], [-86.475117732767, 32.4655300823018], [-86.4753147324104, 32.4634160820837], [-86.4753727330351, 32.4630630817006], [-86.4753867323803, 32.4626670816812], [-86.4754087330201, 32.4623080814719], [-86.4756127323362, 32.4601130812877], [-86.4756137330595, 32.460017080894], [-86.4755767323512, 32.459972081077], [-86.4755067329294, 32.45993508084], [-86.4752517326612, 32.4598860811788], [-86.475260732882, 32.4596560812061], [-86.4752777326005, 32.4595810806928], [-86.4753727321367, 32.4593130811975], [-86.4755787328993, 32.4594140811745], [-86.4763737329427, 32.4600570811336], [-86.4765927332259, 32.4603530806872], [-86.476919733464, 32.4605820814003], [-86.476914733441, 32.4609350808958], [-86.4774237332541, 32.4615110811582], [-86.4782757331988, 32.4621060810734], [-86.4787157334149, 32.4624970811081], [-86.4794537335566, 32.4633460818001], [-86.4818847346157, 32.4635020816434], [-86.4819177342277, 32.4631050815547], [-86.4819077341819, 32.4629600810555], [-86.4818657343491, 32.4628150810808], [-86.481833734562, 32.4627450810878], [-86.481793734379, 32.462680081208], [-86.4816947346449, 32.4625560812141], [-86.4815737342711, 32.4624490810576], [-86.4810287344731, 32.4620920809689], [-86.4807627343342, 32.4619090811902], [-86.4806357341126, 32.461811080957], [-86.4805207344849, 32.4617050811726], [-86.4804677338832, 32.4616470810088], [-86.4803747339967, 32.461526081096], [-86.4802957343541, 32.4613990810377], [-86.4802327337064, 32.4612640813164], [-86.480183734201, 32.4611240811391], [-86.4801547338887, 32.460982081246], [-86.4801437340181, 32.4608380808696], [-86.4801547338887, 32.4606190806136], [-86.4801997340946, 32.4603750806254], [-86.4803017342017, 32.460170081165], [-86.4804357340961, 32.459978081155], [-86.4818407342347, 32.458796080818], [-86.4820197343349, 32.4586360805449], [-86.4821847341913, 32.4584660807016], [-86.4823887344058, 32.4582300806991], [-86.4835197349082, 32.4568490802415], [-86.4843747352258, 32.4559220797672], [-86.4845347350595, 32.4557200794496], [-86.4847447351218, 32.4555030800148], [-86.4849497351612, 32.4552640796344], [-86.4856047354623, 32.4545910796695], [-86.4860297356098, 32.4541420789798], [-86.4860737350924, 32.4540770789561], [-86.4866257354614, 32.4534240789159], [-86.4869657352201, 32.4529930793473], [-86.4871527357162, 32.4527760786503], [-86.4872267353359, 32.4526580792328], [-86.4874037357863, 32.4524140789063], [-86.4877227356285, 32.4520000787606], [-86.487854735873, 32.4518110790832], [-86.4880457356687, 32.4514850785718], [-86.4881407361033, 32.451282078304], [-86.4882817356703, 32.4509390782497], [-86.488616735406, 32.4499590783725], [-86.4886877355511, 32.4497330783256], [-86.4889677359337, 32.4501030787038], [-86.4894717357237, 32.4507950784964], [-86.4897577359541, 32.4512220785367], [-86.489945736275, 32.4514880788936], [-86.4901137365046, 32.4517450790424], [-86.4902857360336, 32.4520250787684], [-86.4903597365518, 32.4521320784203], [-86.49193273692, 32.4547180794722], [-86.4923177368844, 32.4553630792218], [-86.4960457381269, 32.4615150808892], [-86.4966467388999, 32.4625220804769], [-86.4974097391561, 32.463749080653], [-86.4975747390125, 32.4639900806909], [-86.4979817396166, 32.4645370812083], [-86.4983187390022, 32.4649370809217], [-86.4986297393468, 32.4652860812176], [-86.4988457392569, 32.4655140810582], [-86.49976974007, 32.4664510812639], [-86.4999977396756, 32.4666710814253], [-86.5002067399129, 32.4668900813655], [-86.5008077397874, 32.4674470815063], [-86.5013377404152, 32.4677950814962], [-86.5014787399821, 32.4678780816457], [-86.5016237406454, 32.467954081743], [-86.5018937400838, 32.4681310818304], [-86.5034957407644, 32.4686820816185], [-86.503954741247, 32.4688150815064], [-86.5045587414946, 32.4690110817809], [-86.5048117412146, 32.4690990821367], [-86.5060517414968, 32.4694930818479], [-86.5064737421695, 32.4696160817316], [-86.5073957424343, 32.4699130821077], [-86.5085567421755, 32.470268082216], [-86.5087807424816, 32.4704730821855], [-86.5087927421771, 32.4705740817734], [-86.5087657424129, 32.4707700820083], [-86.5087177427324, 32.4708180821709], [-86.508620742648, 32.4708640822713], [-86.5088087429689, 32.4714740823346], [-86.5087747426338, 32.4717530824932], [-86.5088667426953, 32.4718720822922], [-86.5091077427197, 32.4720170820834], [-86.5096607429137, 32.4721830821012], [-86.5098277433183, 32.4721870821159], [-86.5102957431233, 32.4720380825773], [-86.5104237431699, 32.4721270826315], [-86.5103817433371, 32.4722600827359], [-86.510309743367, 32.4723220821361], [-86.5102687433592, 32.4723290825302], [-86.5101487428103, 32.4724400823193], [-86.5101417431376, 32.4724920823508], [-86.5101327429168, 32.4725090827336], [-86.5101337427417, 32.4725360823541], [-86.5100697431676, 32.4726150826848], [-86.5098447430366, 32.4728130822596], [-86.5097727430667, 32.4728580824811], [-86.5096837433782, 32.4729440828756], [-86.5096607429137, 32.4730340824074], [-86.5096447430201, 32.4730680822071], [-86.5096047428371, 32.4731100827], [-86.5095887429437, 32.4731450828428], [-86.5095567431566, 32.4731790826007], [-86.5093717432087, 32.4733380824345], [-86.5092757429492, 32.4733970830161], [-86.5091667431693, 32.4734500828637], [-86.5090667427119, 32.4735180828938], [-86.5089447425131, 32.4735760829904], [-86.5089237425967, 32.4735800829435], [-86.5088237430375, 32.4736500828506], [-86.5087847426794, 32.4737060828884], [-86.508736742999, 32.4737260826229], [-86.5086887424201, 32.4737620828916], [-86.508623743021, 32.4737760826974], [-86.5085347424342, 32.4738110825814], [-86.5083577428823, 32.4739490827715], [-86.5083097423034, 32.474018082787], [-86.5083027426307, 32.4740460830748], [-86.5082057425463, 32.4741290827671], [-86.5080767426749, 32.4741440828768], [-86.5079467429784, 32.4742330831226], [-86.5079087424452, 32.4744060830764], [-86.5078937423768, 32.474509082755], [-86.5078617425897, 32.4745440831119], [-86.5077887427947, 32.4746040832592], [-86.5076037428469, 32.4746210832432], [-86.5075667421386, 32.4746100831202], [-86.507522742656, 32.4746070828109], [-86.5074417424651, 32.4746830832911], [-86.5074127421528, 32.4748060829052], [-86.5073057420227, 32.4749040833955], [-86.5072497419462, 32.4748970832017], [-86.5071767421513, 32.4748970832017], [-86.5070807418919, 32.474919083376], [-86.5067257420645, 32.4751640829575], [-86.5065727419037, 32.4752380830279], [-86.5064757418193, 32.4752670832847], [-86.5063227425567, 32.4753020833469], [-86.5062577422594, 32.4753080831615], [-86.506201742183, 32.4753220834847], [-86.5061687416726, 32.4753440827974], [-86.5061447422814, 32.4753440827974], [-86.5061047420984, 32.4753720834307], [-86.506048742022, 32.4754260832199], [-86.5060017421664, 32.4756340830877], [-86.5058817416174, 32.4757300835058], [-86.5057357420276, 32.4757660829731], [-86.5056697419053, 32.4758030835262], [-86.5055347421862, 32.4759320836565], [-86.5055077415237, 32.476017083048], [-86.505464741866, 32.4762210832303], [-86.505424741683, 32.4762760836052], [-86.5053447422152, 32.4763460836893], [-86.5052477421309, 32.4764190832102], [-86.5051927418793, 32.4764760833764], [-86.5051617419173, 32.4767800831477], [-86.5051327416049, 32.4768390837471], [-86.5048337418542, 32.4771050834776], [-86.5047287413739, 32.4771820836918], [-86.5046407415103, 32.4772160834406], [-86.4996507402442, 32.4754860835371]]], 'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326, 'latestWkid': 4326}}",
    1.66, 'AL', 1, 1001, 0.0004117408484489, 0.11078976964353, 20100]], columns=['BLOCKGROUP_FIPS', 'COUNTY_FIPS', 'FIPS', 'OBJECTID',
'POP20_SQMI', 'POPULATION', 'POPULATION_2020', 'POP_SQMI', 'SHAPE',
'SQMI', 'STATE_ABBR', 'STATE_FIPS', 'STCOFIPS', 'Shape__Area',
'Shape__Length', 'TRACT_FIPS'])
```